# How to make middle portion of sliced image repeat for long menu?

Tags: html, css

[image]

see that the background is not repeated for the long text.

The red/ maroon color is an image sliced as a whole (no middle portion sliced) or in other word its a single image.

Say that I sliced the middle part so that it can repeat as the menu grows longer, how can I include it in the css?

This is how I include the single image currently.

```
ul a:hover{
        background-image: url("<?php echo get_template_directory_uri()?>/images/slices/slanted-hover.gif");
        color:#fff;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        min-width: 50px;
    }
```

Expected result like below, where the whole word is covered by the background image:

[image]

If still not clear, please see here:

All I want to do is,

[image]

I want the black rectangle to be repeated. Ideally when I slice it's going to be there images. So how do I use it as a background for menu (putting together all there images) and repeat the middle (black rectangle) repeat?

Comment: Could you help me out visualize your requirements by posting a pic of how you want your stuff to be done? Sorry but I am not able to understand your problem completely.

Comment: This can be done without any image, which browsers do you need to target?

Comment: @LarsBeck all common browsers, e.g IE11, firefox, Chrome

Comment: Yes it's clear now. Thank you.

Comment: @112233 Alright, see my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not actually need to use any image for that purpose. A simply trick using just [CSS 2D transform](http://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms2d) and [pseudo-elements](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-gencontent) will work fine, and these two specs are widely supported across modern browsers in use.

The only modification you need for your markup is to wrap your link text in an additional `<span>` element, for proper z-index stacking to work.

The only caveat with this trick is that when you apply a skew, part of the skewed pseudo-element will protrude out of the bounding box of the parent element. This protrusion is dependent on the skew angle and the height of the link, but can be accounted for by setting left and right paddings on the `<ul>` element to ensure they don't overflow.

```css
ul {
  background-color: #eee;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0 1.5rem;  /* Spacing to account for skewed edges protruding out of box */
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
ul li a {
  color: #000;
  float: left;
  padding: .75rem 1.5rem;
  position: relative;
  transition: all .25s ease-in-out;
}
ul li a span {
  position: relative;
}
ul li a::before {
  background-color: #b13131;
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  transform: skew(-10deg);
  transition: all .25s ease-in-out;
  opacity: 0;
}
ul li a:hover {
  color: #fff;
}
ul li a:hover::before {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="#"><span>Item 1</span></a></li>
  <li><a href="#"><span>Item 2 that is a little bit too long</span></a></li>
  <li><a href="#"><span>Item 3</span></a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Pure CSS solution, should work in all major browsers including IE >= 9.

```
ul a {
  position: relative;
}

ul a:hover::after {
  content: "";
  z-index: -1;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: -.8em;
  bottom: 0;
  left: -.8em;
  background-color: red;
  transform: skewX(-15deg);
}
```